# UIView.addSubview() Unexpectedly found nil

Tags: ios, swift

Here's is my problem:

I have a function within a class. That class has an outlet, called `embeddedView`. When the function is called within the class, it can access that outlet, but when called elsewhere, it fails.

```
func embedView(_ newView: UIViewController){
        self.navigationItem.title = selectedView
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: Style.sectionHeaderTitleColor]
        newView.view.frame = self.embeddedView.bounds
        self.embeddedView.addSubview((newView.view)!) //This is the line that fails from AppDelegate
        addChildViewController(newView)
        newView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
 }
```

When called from within the class, that function has no problemos, but when called from AppDelegate, it fails, with the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`, as embeddedView is declared a `!`

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: That's because the outlet is nil when called from AppDelegate. Depending on what you're trying to do you can either check whether it is nil when adding it as subview or create the view in code rather than storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a strong reference for your variable `self.embeddedView` in `AppDelegate`. Generally there is no UIView available in `AppDelegate` class as it's not associated with any UIView. `AppDelegate` is the start point from where all other UIViews are initialized. The reason for this error is that your view `self.embeddedView` is actually `nil` at `AppDelegate` however when you use the same inside a `UIViewController` class you have that object available and it works.

Comment: Ok, but how would this be solved? Because 3D Touch is handled in AppDelegate, and I am trying to edit an existing view

Comment: Make a reference for the ViewController which you need to access in `AppDelegate`. and also put an if condition to check it's `nil` value.